# Master one commit ahead, Azure Devops

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am following the basic Git flow by writing feature branches which merge to `develop` and then `develop` to `master` ever so often.

To keep `develop` and `master` in sync I am having to force push `master` from a local copy I have made from `develop`.

---

So at that point `develop` and `master` are **0 commits ahead - 0 commits behind**.

The next time I create a PR from `develop` to `master` it works, but the time after that it has conflicts because `master` is **1 commit ahead - n commits behind**.

The only commit that `master` had that `develop` didn't was the merge commit created from the previous PR. I have never had issues like this with either Github or Bitbucket.

What is happening?

Answer (score 2):

> The only commit that master had that develop didn't was the merge commit created from the previous PR

That means you should rebase your `develop` branch (that you have not pushed yet since the last PR) on top of `master`.
And then make your new PR from develop.

```
 git checkout master
 git pull

 git checkout develop
 git rebase master
```

That way, only new commits (since the updated master) would be considered in the new PR.

Comment: Do you have any insight on how to prevent that, in the future, instead of needing to rebase?

Comment: @theblindprophet not exactly, considering rebase is part of the normal workflow of submitting a PR: the idea is for the PR to include only *new* commit on top of the target branch, since the merge to said target branch would then be trivial (fast-forward). So you rebase first locally, then create a PR.

Comment: Thanks, Ive never needed to take that approach. Will give it a try.